# SQL Alter Table Foreign key On Delete

Tags: sql

I have a table in my database called trains with these columns:

`id`, `name`, `station`.

Station is the foreign key to other table `stations`. When I delete some specific row from `stations`, since `trains` references to this table, I get an error. Hence, what I try to do is to do `alter table` on `trains` and add `on delete set null` attribute to `station` column, like this:

```
alter table trains alter column station on delete set null;
```

However, this seems to be the wrong syntax and I can't find the right one, which can make this without removing the whole table and creating it again (so I need to use this `alter` command).

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then you cannot alter a foreign key constraint to add on delete. First drop the constraint and then create a new one.

```
ALTER TABLE trains 
DROP CONSTRAINT constraintname;

ALTER TABLE trains 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_station
  FOREIGN KEY (child_column_name) 
  REFERENCES stations(parent_column_name) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```